# Find and count consecutive records in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

I have an app that tracks employee times.  Employees are required to have at least 2 days off every 12 days...  An employee should enter a record with boolean true for day_off...but, in case they don't I also want to find breaks in days that could also days off.  I am trying to simply count records whos date decrements by one day, starting from the boolean day_off Or break in consecutive dates...and ending on a given date.

This is the helper I am working on

```
  def consecutive_days_on(user, dutylog)
    # dutylog will be supplied via a loop

    last_day_off = user.dutylogs.where("entry_date < ?", dutylog.entry_date).where(day_off: true).last
    start_date = dutylog.entry_date

      if last_day_off.present?
        end_date = last_day_off.entry_date
        # if the user logged their days off
      else
        end_date = user.dutylogs.where("entry_date < ?", dutylog.entry_date).last.entry_date
        # as of now this just finds the last record...it needs to iterate and increment date to find a break in days on
        # to find break in consecutive dates...if user did not log days off
      end

      user.dutylogs.where("entry_date >= ? AND entry_date <= ?", start_date, end_date).count
      # count the records between the two dates...to find consecutive days on
  end
```

Comment: Stick to conventions: put comments *above* statements, not below. Sorry I can't be of any other use than dropping that pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored my helper...and it works.  I decided to rely on the user entering a day as off in their log...and not assuming that a break in entered days could be considered a day off.

```
   def consecutive_days_on(user, dutylog)
     last_day_off = user.dutylogs.where(day_off: true).where("entry_date < ?", dutylog.entry_date).select(:entry_date).last
     start_date = dutylog.entry_date

      if last_day_off.present?
        end_date = last_day_off.entry_date
      else
        end_date = dutylog.entry_date
      end

      a = user.dutylogs.where("entry_date >= ? AND entry_date <= ?", end_date, start_date).count
      a-1
   end
```